# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

I have a `CustomUser` that extends the `AbstractUser` as follows

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    USERTYPE_CHOICES = [(1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C")]
    usertype = models.IntegerField(choices = USERTYPE_CHOICES, default = 1)
```

I have the following lines in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'login_register_service_hub.apps.LoginRegisterServiceHubConfig',
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login_register_service_hub.CustomUser'
```

**Everything works as expected however**:

I am trying to implement a custom authentication backend and I do this by including the following

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


#Check for the is_active property
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I update my `settings.py` with the following:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = {'login_register_service_hub.EmailBackend',}
```

However as soon as I run

```
 python3 manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error

`"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'login_register_service_hub.CustomUser' that has not been installed`

The interesting remark is that the command fails only if I import `ModelBackend` (even if I comment out the `EmailBackend` definition)

Comment: Can you try dropping your db, creating a new db, deleting all your migrations and finally makemigrations and migrate again?

Comment: What's in `login_register_service_hub`? I notice that the backend is imported directly from the app, is the model in a `models.py` file?

Comment: @engin_ipek  I deleted the db, the migrations but running makemigrations fails with the same error

Comment: @IainShelvington The definitions above are in the `models.py` of `login_register_service_hub`

Comment: "the command fails only if I import ModelBackend" why is it being imported directly from the app? Try moving the backend to "backends.py" and import from there

Comment: Change your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting to import 'login_register_service_hub.backend.EmailBackend'

Comment: The `__init__.py` of an app should very rarely ever import anything

Comment: @IainShelvington If you want to go ahead and answer it I'll accept it.

Comment: Try moving the backend to "backends.py" and import from there @IainShelvington agreed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *generally* not import things in/from an apps `__init__.py`. Move your backend to `login_register_service_hub/backends.py` and then update your setting

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['login_register_service_hub.backends.EmailBackend']
```